# ADF pipeline - trigger next activity after Web activity url execution completion

Tags: azure-data-factory

1. I have an ADF pipeline that triggers the SSAS model refresh.
2. SSAS model refresh activity is in a web activity that runs a post URL elated to the SSAS
   model. This runs for 4 hours.
3. I need to perform a step after this web activity.
4. If I connect the activity directly to the subsequent activity, the subsequent activity
   runs immediately after triggering the first activity.

Eg:

WebATask -> TaskB

TaskB runs immediately even though the URL triggered in WebATask is not complete.

5. I want the URL triggered in WebATask to be complete before triggering TaskB.
6. For that I have introduced a wait activity in between as shown below.

WebATask -> **WaitTask** -> TaskB

For this, I have hardcoded, 4.15 hours in the **WaitTask** which is working for the time being but not a concrete solution.

Is there any way to achieve this without using **WaitTask**?

Pipeline Image:
[image]

Comment: can you add image of pipeline for better undrstanding?

Comment: Added Pratik. Please check

Comment: is your WebATask is showing executed successful before SSAS model refresh?

Comment: Yes. you are rite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve this without using **WaitTask**?

You can use the [Reat API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh) to get the status of SSAS refresh and if its status is **succeeded** then you can call next activity(task).

[image]

- Here first we started the Refresh using the web activity that runs a post URL.
- Then in next web activity we are fetching the status of the SSAS refresh using rest api.
- After this using filter activity, we are filtering out refresh id.
- Then under until we are fetching the status of the SSAS refresh using rest Api and refresh id till we get failed or succeed as status.
- Under if activity based on status, you could perform your respective task.

This project [link](https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/ADFv2/ProcessAzureAS.json) provides the complete JSON for the ADF structure mentioned above.

**pipeline.json**

```json
{
    "name": "ProcessAzureAS",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Login",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": {
                        "value": "@concat('https://login.microsoftonline.com/',pipeline().parameters.TenantID,'/oauth2/token')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    },
                    "body": {
                        "value": "@concat('grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://*.asazure.windows.net&client_id=',pipeline().parameters.ClientID,'&client_secret=',encodeUriComponent(pipeline().parameters.ClientSecret))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "UntilRefreshComplete",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "FilterToCurrentRefresh",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@not(equals(activity('GetAzureASRefreshStatus').output.status,'inProgress'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "GetAzureASRefreshStatus",
                            "type": "WebActivity",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Wait30Seconds",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "url": {
                                    "value": "@concat('https://',pipeline().parameters.Region,'.asazure.windows.net/servers/',pipeline().parameters.Server,'/models/',pipeline().parameters.DatabaseName,'/refreshes/',activity('FilterToCurrentRefresh').output.Value[0].refreshId)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "method": "GET",
                                "headers": {
                                    "Authorization": {
                                        "value": "@concat(string(activity('Login').output.token_type),' ',string(activity('Login').output.access_token))",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Wait30Seconds",
                            "type": "Wait",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "waitTimeInSeconds": 30
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "FilterToCurrentRefresh",
                "type": "Filter",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "GetAzureASRefreshes",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@json(activity('GetAzureASRefreshes').output.Response)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "condition": {
                        "value": "@greaterOrEquals(item().startTime,addseconds(activity('StartProcessingAzureAS').output.startTime,-30))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "StartProcessingAzureAS",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Login",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": {
                        "value": "@concat('https://',pipeline().parameters.Region,'.asazure.windows.net/servers/',pipeline().parameters.Server,'/models/',pipeline().parameters.DatabaseName,'/refreshes')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": {
                            "value": "@concat(string(activity('Login').output.token_type),' ',string(activity('Login').output.access_token))",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    },
                    "body": {
                        "Type": "Full",
                        "CommitMode": "transactional",
                        "MaxParallelism": 10,
                        "RetryCount": 2
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "IfFailed",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "UntilRefreshComplete",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(activity('GetAzureASRefreshStatus').output.status,'failed')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "ThrowErrorOnFailure",
                            "type": "Fail",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "message": "@string(activity('GetAzureASRefreshStatus').output)",
                                "errorCode": "100"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "GetAzureASRefreshes",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "StartProcessingAzureAS",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": {
                        "value": "@concat('https://',pipeline().parameters.Region,'.asazure.windows.net/servers/',pipeline().parameters.Server,'/models/',pipeline().parameters.DatabaseName,'/refreshes')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": {
                            "value": "@concat(string(activity('Login').output.token_type),' ',string(activity('Login').output.access_token))",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    },
                    "body": {
                        "Type": "Full",
                        "CommitMode": "transactional",
                        "MaxParallelism": 10,
                        "RetryCount": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "TenantID": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "ClientID": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "ClientSecret": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "SubscriptionID": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "Region": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "Server": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "DatabaseName": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "Azure AS"
        },
        "annotations": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```